# Randomly Select Columns to Shuffle of a Two-Dimensional Dataframe

Tags: dataframe, numpy, random, shuffle, type-2-dimension

I would like to randomly select a few columns of a 2 dimensional dataframe, and shuffle the values within those columns.  I can easily shuffle all values (column-wise) of the dataframe, but I am looking to only do so to a randomly selected few.

For instance, take the 6x6 dataframe below:

```
      0    1     2     3     4     5
0     5    3     7     1     2     9
1     1    7     5     3     0     8
2     0    2     7     1     6     5
3     8    4     2     1     9     7
4     2    9     5     6     3     4
5     7    5     8     2     1     0
```

Randomly selecting a few of the 6 columns, note the following output:

```
      0    1     2     3     4     5
0     2    9     7     1     2     4
1     5    7     5     3     0     0
2     7    2     7     1     6     5
3     8    3     2     1     9     7
4     1    5     5     6     3     9
5     0    4     8     2     1     8
```

The above shows the 1st, 2nd and last column shuffled, and all others remain as is.

The following code allows me to shuffle all columns:

```
import numpy as np
df = np.random.random((6,6))
np.random.random(df)
```

And, yet, after many attempts, I have been unable to modify this to only select (randomly) a few columns.
Any advice will be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this input example:

```
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(4*5).reshape(4, 5, order='F'))

   0  1   2   3   4
0  0  4   8  12  16
1  1  5   9  13  17
2  2  6  10  14  18
3  3  7  11  15  19
```

I would use:

```
import numpy as np

# random number of columns
n = np.random.randint(0, df.shape[1])

# pick n random columns
cols = np.random.choice(df.columns, 3, replace=False)

# shuffle them independently
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda s: np.random.choice(s, len(s), replace=False))
```

You can even vectorize the last step with [`permuted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.permuted.html) if efficiency is important:

```
rng = np.random.default_rng()

# n = rng.integers(0, df.shape[1])
# cols = rng.choice(df.columns, n, replace=False)

df[cols] = rng.permuted(df[cols], axis=0)
```

Example output:

```
   0  1   2   3   4
0  1  4  11  14  16
1  0  5   8  15  17
2  3  6  10  13  18
3  2  7   9  12  19
```

Comment: Wow - that's awesome.  Can we make the number of columns selected be a random as well?

Comment: Yes: `cols = np.random.choice(df.columns, np.random.randint(0, df.shape[1]), replace=False)`

Comment: That's perfect.  Thank you to all!!!!

Comment: @user23487612 I added an edit with an improved alternative for the last step ;)

Comment: excellent!  I will definitely use this.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(36).reshape(6,-1, order='F'), columns=[*'ABCDEF'])
cols_shuf = np.random.choice(df.columns, 3, replace=False)
# array(['E', 'C', 'A'], dtype=object)

df.assign(**df[cols_shuf].apply(lambda x: x.sample(frac=1).to_numpy()))
```

Output:

```
   A   B   C   D   E   F
0  2   6  15  18  28  30
1  1   7  16  19  27  31
2  0   8  17  20  29  32
3  3   9  14  21  25  33
4  5  10  12  22  26  34
5  4  11  13  23  24  35
```

Comment: Almost the same, great minds think alike, I originally wanted to use `sample` and eventually decided to go full-numpy ;)

Comment: I am going to employ both of these solutions throughout the course of this project - thank you both :).